# Grails: @Secured annotation for OR roles

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, grails-3.0

In Grails I am using

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

@Secured({'ROLE_COMPANY', 'ROLE_BACKEND_ADMIN'})
class MobileSendersController {
```

but it's putting AND relation between roles. I need an OR relation. Access is allowed to `ROLE_COMPANY` or `ROLE_BACKEND_ADMIN`.

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36892152/are-multiple-roles-allowed-in-the-secured-annotation-with-or-condition-in-spr) the answers are advising to use `@PreAuthorize`. I tried it in Grails but no luck. Maybe I need to modify pre- and post-annotations but I can't find the config.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182034/grails-spring-security-role-and-group will give a clue in how to get role groups working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would solve the problem -

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

@Secured(['ROLE_COMPANY', 'ROLE_BACKEND_ADMIN'])
class MobileSendersController {
```

Refer to doc http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#securedAnnotations

Answer (score 8):

If you take a look at the [documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#secured-annotation) fore `@Secured` you'll see that it uses SpEL expressions ([documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#expressions), about this), so you can do quite a few things. In particular, you would want to use `hasAnyRole()` like this:

`@Secured("hasAnyRole('ROLE_COMPANY', 'ROLE_BACKEND_ADMIN')")`

Comment: Josh, I've changed the accepted answer as @Ankit Agrawal answer is more Grails.

Comment: @zatziky, okay, not sure what makes his answer more Grails than mine. They both use the same plugin and the same annotation. Your choice though.

Comment: Josh, you may be right. I find it better as it's shorter. It's arguable because for newcommers the `hasAnyRole` is more comprehensive. So you both share the accepted answer.

Comment: @zatziky no worries at all, just glad you got the issue sorted out!

Comment: haha @JoshuaMoore i liked your answer more on that first day so gave you an upmark :) I am with you

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have two roles for one controller? Perhaps consider having a single privilege for your controller and then you can add the privilege to your ROLE_COMPANY and ROLE_BACKEND_ADMIN roles.

Comment: Interesting idea. But. Imagine you have roles A, B, C and Controllers C1, C2, C3. C1 can be accessed by A and B. C2 by B, C. C3 by A only. With your approach every single controller would need a special permission. The way with OR is more granular.